# Web Module does not find the classes of another module

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, maven, websphere

I use maven for my project structure.
I have a web module in my project which depends on another module which I defined thus:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.stack.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>Modul_Basic</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If i run maven install . It creates a war file in target and this war file includes Modul_Basic jar in lib directory. 
The problem is: if i deploy on a server (Websphere) in Myeclipse. It does not pack the dependent modules.

How should I deploy/build my web module?

Comment: @BalusC have you got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is your dependency packaged as war? Possibly you can try [overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-overlay.html) to fix that

Comment: Dependency Modul is an EJB Modul. Therefore it is packaged as jar.

Comment: Why would you have a web module dependent on an EJB Module. This does not sound right to me.

Comment: @Manglu Web Module needs the entities in EJB module